# Passing two nodes in PHP multidimensional array and get the level difference between them

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in PHP which looks like the following code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6898
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 8214
                            [ParentID] => 6898
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5595
                            [ParentID] => 6898
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 7238
                                            [ParentID] => 5595
                                        )   
                                )    
                        )   
                )    
        )   
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8216
            [ParentID] => 
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7046
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5555
                            [ParentID] => 7046
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 7294
                                            [ParentID] => 5555
                                        )    
                                )   
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5706
                            [ParentID] => 7046
                        )    
                )    
        )   
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5884
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 7431
                            [ParentID] => 5884
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 5618
                                            [ParentID] => 7431
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 6993
                            [ParentID] => 5884
                        )    
                )   
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6002
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5801
                            [ParentID] => 6002
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 6615
                            [ParentID] => 6002
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 6595
                                            [ParentID] => 6615
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                )   
        )    
    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8119
            [ParentID] => 
        )    
    [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8116
            [ParentID] => 
        )    
    [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5992
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 7614
                            [ParentID] => 5992
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 7647
                                            [ParentID] => 7614
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )   
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 8215
                            [ParentID] => 5992
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [8] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5690
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 8188
                            [ParentID] => 5690
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5678
                            [ParentID] => 5690
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [9] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5825
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 6842
                            [ParentID] => 5825
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5653
                            [ParentID] => 5825
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 6490
                                            [ParentID] => 5653
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [ID] => 7737
                                                            [ParentID] => 6490
                                                        )    
                                                )    
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [10] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8114
            [ParentID] => 
        )   
    [11] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8113
            [ParentID] => 
        )    
    [12] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7826
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 7871
                            [ParentID] => 7826
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 5891
                                            [ParentID] => 7871
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5983
                            [ParentID] => 7826
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6898
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 8214
                            [ParentID] => 6898
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5595
                            [ParentID] => 6898
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 7238
                                            [ParentID] => 5595
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                )    
        )   
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8216
            [ParentID] => 
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7046
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5555
                            [ParentID] => 7046
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 7294
                                            [ParentID] => 5555
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5706
                            [ParentID] => 7046
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5884
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 7431
                            [ParentID] => 5884
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 5618
                                            [ParentID] => 7431
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 6993
                            [ParentID] => 5884
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6002
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5801
                            [ParentID] => 6002
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 6615
                            [ParentID] => 6002
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 6595
                                            [ParentID] => 6615
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8119
            [ParentID] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8116
            [ParentID] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5992
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 7614
                            [ParentID] => 5992
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 7647
                                            [ParentID] => 7614
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 8215
                            [ParentID] => 5992
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [8] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5690
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 8188
                            [ParentID] => 5690
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5678
                            [ParentID] => 5690
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [9] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5825
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 6842
                            [ParentID] => 5825
                        )    
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5653
                            [ParentID] => 5825
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 6490
                                            [ParentID] => 5653
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [ID] => 7737
                                                            [ParentID] => 6490
                                                        )    
                                                )    
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [10] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8114
            [ParentID] => 
        )    
    [11] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8113
            [ParentID] => 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7826
            [ParentID] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 7871
                            [ParentID] => 7826
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 5891
                                            [ParentID] => 7871
                                        )    
                                )   
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 5983
                            [ParentID] => 7826
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
```

This is the hierarchical array in which I want to pass two node ID's something like this -> getLevelDifference(7826, 5891) and it should give 2 as result or a function in which I can get that level child array like -> getLevelChild(7826, 2) and it should return 5891 as the result or other childs of the same level ?

Comment: Yeah, you're missing your code

Comment: what the problem you got?

Comment: I just want a function which works as described above?